# Whether the rt task keeps taking CPU when there is only a rt task and a common task?

Tags: linux, scheduler

In the function `pick_next_task` (kernel/sched/core.c),I found code like this:

```
for_each_class(class) {
        p = class->pick_next_task(rq, prev, rf);
        if (p) {
            if (unlikely(p == RETRY_TASK))
                goto again;
            return p;
        }
    }
```

I wonder Whether the rt task keeps taking CPU when there is only a rt task and a common task?Because the loop above will always choose the rt task till it has been done.
Actually, I found `sysctl_sched_rt_period` which is used to limit the running time of rt tasks in a period.But I didn't find where it works in `re_sched_class`.(The kernel version is 4.14.255).

Comment: Where did you find this function? Is it in the kernel source code or did you write it by yourself?

Comment: The source code.